# Flutter dialog not closing completely

Tags: flutter, dart

We have a Flutter dialog that when we click Ok and it sends the user home... the dialog lingers on the screen even after sending them home and then goes away which is annoying.

Here is the code for the dialog:

```
 Future<void> _requestSupportDialog(BuildContext context, User user, Features features) {
    return showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
    title: Text('Success! You have been entered into the support queue'),
    content: const Text('Support it on its way'),
    actions: <Widget>[
      FlatButton(
        child: Text('Ok'),
        onPressed: () {
          // Send them HOME.
          Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new FlutterReduxApp(user: user, features: features)));
         },
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context)=>Home(son: 0,)));
```

Comment: Please refrain from answering with code-only. Note that you are not only answering to the OP, but also to any future readers of the question. Thus, please edit the post to contain an explanation as to why this line of code works.

Answer (score 0):

Before pushing to a new route, try to pop first to dismiss the dialog.

```
Navigator.of(context).pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();

Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context)=>Home(son: 0,)));